Blazor Radzen hybrid Datagrid filter
I'm trying to create an "Hybrid Filter" it should have a row with manual filtering and the other rows should have the default Advanced Mode Radzen filter
Im trying to achieve this trough LoadData
How could i do this?
I'm really stuck on this one
Im trying to achieve this trough LoadData
async Task OnDataGridLoadData(LoadDataArgs args)
{
    // Get the full dataset
    IEnumerable<ObraModel> filteredData = Enumerable.Empty<ObraModel>();

    // Check if there's a filter applied to the manually filtered column
    if (args.Filters.Any(f => f.Property == "Situacao"))
    {
        // Apply custom filtering for the specific column
        var manualFilter = args.Filters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Property == "Situacao");
        if (manualFilter != null)
        {
            // // Example of applying manual filtering (adjust as necessary for your logic)
            // var filterValue = manualFilter.Value?.ToString();
            // filteredData = filteredData.Where(item => item.YourManualFilteredProperty.Contains(filterValue));
            filteredData = await getFilteredWorkshets("Situacao", "N");
        }

        // Remove the manual filter from the default filtering logic to avoid double filtering
        args.Filters = args.Filters.Where(f => f.Property != "Situacao").ToList();
    }

    // Apply the default filtering for other columns using Radzen’s built-in logic
    //filteredData = Radzen.Filter.Apply(filteredData, args.Filters);

    // Pagination and sorting
    filteredData = filteredData.Skip(args.Skip.Value).Take(args.Top.Value).ToList();

    // Pagination
    obrasList = filteredData;
    count = filteredData.Count();

    //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

I tried this but it is not working for me
I can only filter through "my" filter and radzen doesn't seem to filter the rows without my custom filter
